# Mixed length object type in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to use the pandas library to store mixed length objects.

Let's say for instance that I want to have a dataframe with two columns: the first one storing a float and the second one storing a list of float. 
What is the best way to do this in pandas, bearing in mind that I want to be able to sort the data using the first column.

Comment: First try to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'a': [.1,.2,.3],
    'b': [ [.1,.2], [.3,.4,.5,.6,.7], [.8,.9,1.] ],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print df
```

result:

```
     a                          b
0  0.1                 [0.1, 0.2]
1  0.2  [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7]
2  0.3            [0.8, 0.9, 1.0]
```

reversed

```
print df.sort('a', ascending=False)

     a                          b
2  0.3            [0.8, 0.9, 1.0]
1  0.2  [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7]
0  0.1                 [0.1, 0.2]
```